# What's the simplest way to create a scope within a method?

Tags: java, scope

I'm not looking for best practice, so bad practices and hacks are acceptable for this case.

Suppose I want to reuse a variable name with different types within the same method.

For example:

```
public static void scopeExample() {
    if (true) {
        Foo bar = new Foo();
    }
    // "bar" is out of scope here

    if (true) {
        Snack bar = new Snack();
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to scope `foo` so I can reuse its name with different types than `if (true) {...}`?

Comment: For a bit of background: I am building a JUnit test. I have several child classes of a shared parent. I want to set non-shared values on the child types. I don't want to have to cast or have each one have a different name. The solution was to put each one in its own scope (using `if (true) {...}`), use it, then discard it at the scope's end. Now I'm just trying to clean/shorten things a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new scope can be made with `{ ... }`:

```
{
    Foo bar = new Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a statement block:

```
{
    ...
}
```